# Simplify regex/ exclude parts from match

Tags: python, regex

I am struggling with a regex that should capture all comma's between two quotes:

I currently obtained

```
("[^",]+)(,)([^"]+")
```

Unfortunately, this matches all text/ digits such as "2132134,23132"

Can anyone help me to transform the regex to just include the comma as a match (2nd group)?

Another example doesn't work for my sample data, unfortunately.

```
,(?=[^"]*"[^"]*(?:"[^"]*"[^"]*)*$)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say, you want to replace all commas between two quotes with a semi-colon.

Use [this](https://tio.run/##LY29DsIwDIT3PIXlJYmwurCBeBIEEj8ujVSSyHEK9OVDK7jlhvvuLn90SHHbWnjmJArC5s79YnkM6ma/M7BIWKtEmLuHpJqd79b8cmNnyRLYvfXGFDiATZEJ9ZVIB2FG6lMVwj5MTCW8qfDEEa0RLnXUtSHclXp1YvF4xtMGl7nfN0HxJkuI6v60b@0L):

```py
import re
def replit(z):
    return z.group().replace(',', ';')

s = 'one,"two,three",four,"five,six,seven"'
results = re.sub(r'"[^"]+"', replit, s)
print(results)
```

**Results**: `one,"two;three",four,"five;six;seven"`

Comment: Excellent, somehow the re.sub function for some csv's decided to match the comma's outside the quotes, but this function works for all of my files.

Answer (score 1):

Use `re.findall` and turn off the first and third capture groups:

```py
inp = '"2132134,23132"'
matches = re.findall(r'(?:"[^",]+)(,)(?:[^"]+")', inp)
print(matches)  # [',']
```